# How to alias array deconstruction in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to know if it possible to deconstruct (in my case `x`) an array and create an alias in order to avoid issues with reserved keywords.

Here an example, but it gives me an error. Any idea how to solve it? Thanks

```
   const mk = (data) =>
      data.map((x, idx) => {
        const [a, b, for:xxx, d] = x
        return {
          a,
          b,
          for:xxx, // I want create an object with for property name
          d
        }
      })
```

Comment: Use quotation marks? `{ "for": xxx }`

Comment: Just replace: `const [a, b, for:xxx, d] = x` with `const [a, b, xxx, d] = x`. https://jsfiddle.net/6974zk8o/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up objects and arrays. You are tying to use an alias on a array deconstruction.

If you deconstruct an array, there is no need for an alias

```js
const x = [
  'a',
  'b',
  'd',
  'for',
];

const [
  a,
  b,
  d,
  xxx,
] = x;

console.log({
  a,
  b,
  xxx,
  d
});
```

---

If you are deconstructing an object, using `for` isn't a problem.

```js
const x = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  d: 'd',
  for: 'for',
};

const {
  a,
  b,
  for: xxx,
  d,
} = x;

console.log({
  a,
  b,
  xxx,
  d
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the context of an array, deconstructing `for: xxx` does not make any sense. This only works for an object having a `for` property (`const {a, b, for: xxx, d } = x;`).

`xxx` is simply the third element of the given array.
The following might do it:

```
const mk = (data) =>
  data.map((x: any, idx: any) => {
    const [a, b, c, d] = x;
    return {
      a,
      b,
      for: c, // I want create an object with for property name
      d,
    }
  })
```